# Extendible hashing probability calculation

Tags: database, hash

Consider an extendible hash index, whose each bin fits
N entries. What is the probability that an overflowing bin should
treated retroactively? "Treated retroactively" means that all the records of the bin should be transferred to
one of two new bins that are created.

I created the bins for N = 2,3,4 , but I can't find a pattern. For N = 2, I created 6 bins, for N = 3 I created 14 bins, and for N = 4 I created 28 bins. I believe that the probability looks somewhat like this: 2/..... , as we have 2 bins that can store all the original values after the split, however I can't place N in the probability.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The probability that an overflowing bin should be treated retroactively depends on the number of entries in the bin and the number of bins in the hash table

assuming that we have m bins in the hash table and each bin can store up to N entries -- he probability that a bin overflows with k entries are given by the probability mass function of the binomial distribution

`P(k) = C(N,k) * (1/m)^k * (1 - 1/m)^(N-k) //where C(N,k) is the binomial coefficient`

if a bin overflows with k entries -- we need to create two new bins and transfer all the k entries to one of them -- the probability that we choose the correct bin is 1/2 -- the probability that an overflowing bin should be treated retroactively is

```
P_retro = sum(k=0 to N-1) P(k) * 1/2
```

where we sum over all possible values of k, from 0 to N-1, because if a bin overflows with N or more entries -- we cannot treat it retroactively

plug values to find pattern

- for N=2 and m=6

```
P_retro = sum(k=0 to 1) C(2,k) * (1/6)^k * (5/6)^(2-k) * 1/2
= (1/6)^0 * (5/6)^2 * 1/2 + C(2,1) * (1/6)^1 * (5/6)^1 * 1/2
= 5/24
```

- for N=3 and m=14

```
P_retro = sum(k=0 to 2) C(3,k) * (1/14)^k * (13/14)^(3-k) * 1/2
= (1/14)^0 * (13/14)^3 * 1/2 + C(3,1) * (1/14)^1 * (13/14)^2 * 1/2 + C(3,2) * (1/14)^2 * (13/14)^1 * 1/2
= 71/364
```

- for N=4 and m=28

```
P_retro = sum(k=0 to 3) C(4,k) * (1/28)^k * (27/28)^(4-k) * 1/2
= (1/28)^0 * (27/28)^4 * 1/2 + C(4,1) * (1/28)^1 * (27/28)^3 * 1/2 + C(4,2) * (1/28)^2 * (27/28)^2 * 1/2 + C(4,3) * (1/28)^3 * (27/28)^1 * 1/2
= 1073/54912
```

as N and m increase -- probability of retroactive treatment should decrease(because the probability of a bin overflowing with many entries becomes smaller)

as N increases -- probability of retroactive treatment should increase(it becomes more likely that a bin will overflow with N-1 or fewer entries)

the exact relationship between N, m, and P_retro is not clear without further analysis